# Match Date Range With Label

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'd like to match the date range label with specific dates.

I have a table with date range & label (in `DateRange` sheet):

[image]

I'd like to apply the label to the qualifying dates and results as such:

[image]

How can this be achieved with Google Sheets formula?

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O1rZUstDNSXPdUVXvaDfPO4rAQs2cJWHimfGxbddtNU/edit#gid=858702648

Comment: are you interested in non-dragging one cell solution?

Comment: @player0 sure, that would be nice as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"Name"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(DATE(A2:A, B2:B, C2:C)<=MAX(DateRange!B:B), 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DATE(A2:A, B2:B, C2:C), DateRange!A1:C, 3)), )))}
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

One way (adapted from [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/74119)) is, in F2 and copied down to suit:

```
=query(DateRange!A:C,"select C where A<=date '"&Text(date(A2,B2,C2),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and B>=date '"&text(date(A2,B2,C2),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' ",0)
```